# Where's the best place to add weight to a Pinewood Derby car?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, friction

A little background: a Pinewood Derby car is a small wooden car that races down an inclined track, powered only by gravity. You are allowed to add weight to the car up to a certain limit.

[Here is a recommendation](http://www.scoutorama.com/derby/derby_display.cfm?race_id=22) to add the weight to the upper back of the car, to maximize the potential energy. My own gut feel is to add it so that the weight is evenly distributed between all 4 wheels. I'd like some advice that is well grounded in science.

Comment: The talk about "maximizing potential energy" is nonsense.  Except for some probably-negligible effects like the effect on slipping, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub, that was my thought too - technobabble nonsense. Thus the impetus for asking the question.

Comment: @Mark Well, it does actually maximize potential energy, but that doesn't mean the speed will be higher.  What matters is the potential energy change.  Actually, there is a very small effect.  Weight at the very back of the car falls a little bit more, because the  car starts at a tilt.  This means weight at the back would be a very slight bit better, but it's small.  I might have time to write a real answer later tonight.

Comment: @Mark E: Actually there is only that effect if the finish line is on level ground.

Comment: @Joe Yes.  As I recall it usually is.  It's been a long time since I was a Cub scout though.

Comment: @Joe, the typical track starts at a large incline and gradually levels out to almost flat. I won't have access to the actual track until this weekend.

Comment: Ah I see, well in that case there may be a small advantage to placing it towards the rear. I must admit, I somewhat misunderstood what a pinewood derby car is. I would imagine in that setting, however, that friction will play a much bigger role (and to a small extent aerodynamics).

Comment: I've updated my answer below.

Comment: There's a [blog post](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2010/12/pinewood-derby-physics/) related to this on Dot Physics, but looking over it again I don't think it discusses this particular aspect (mass _distribution_) of the construction.

Comment: Who wins in such a contest? A car which runs farthest down the lane, or the car who passes first at a certain finish line? The value or drawback of the wheels inertial momentum depends on that.  In general I think friction is the most important factor, and as long as one has to stick with the purchased original parts, not much can be done exept avoiding too much contact of the wheels with the guiding rail. (precision of guidance, and construction of the inner edge of the wheels

Comment: @Georg, the winner is the first across the finish line. Thanks for your thoughts on the wheels, I believe you are right.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: Having totally misunderstood what a pinewood derby car was, my previous answer probably wasn't very helpful (I thought it was like a go-cart). Here is a proper answer:

First off, let me say the recommendation you read is still wrong, for reasons that will be seen in a minute.

[image: Diagram]

The car starts off inclined at an angle $\theta$, with the additional mass a distance $x$ behind the front axle, and a distance $h$ above the line passing through both axles. The change in height of the additional mass relative to the front axle is then given by $d_x + d_h$, where $d_x$ is the decrease in relative elevation of the point a distance $x$ behind the front axle on the line between the two axles, and $d_h$ is the decrease in relative elevation between the mass relative and this point. Clearly, $d_x = x \sin(\theta)$ and $d_h = h (\cos(\theta) - 1)$. Notice that $d_h$ is negative, since the change in relative elevation actually increases for positive $h$. Thus the total change in height (which is proportional to the additional potential energy) is given by $\Delta H = x\sin(\theta) - h(1-\cos(\theta))$. Thus, the best position for the additional mass is very low down (even below the line of the axles if possible), at the back.

Comment: The track is a straight line with no turning, and there is a raised guide in the middle between the wheels to keep the car on a straight line. I probably should have mentioned that in the original question.

Comment: @Joe Good advice in general.  The particular question the OP has in mind is a car that just goes down a straight track, so lots of these turn out to be non-issues http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tC5qRw7QhLA

Comment: Ah ok, so in that case most of the handling concerns are not an issue, so it is less important where you place it but you will still maximize stability by placing it in this position.

Comment: @Joe: Can I suggest that you edit your answer to remove the incorrect part in the beginning? I'd like to upvote your correct answer, but I'm hesitant to do so when the correct answer is only included as an "update" to an incorrect answer. You don't need to preserve your previous response, IMO. The goal is to provide a correct and clear answer; there is no obligation to preserve a record of our errors :)

Comment: @Colin: I did so just before you posted that comment, so I guess you were already typing when I did the update.

Comment: @joe: Yes indeed. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @joe Nice work.  It might be helpful to see how much a contribution this is.  For example, suppose the track drops about $2m$ and the car is about $10cm$ long.  Then could a car with the weight in back be $5$% faster or $.05$% faster?

Comment: @Mark This isn't possible without knowing more about the car. The change in potential energy is $m \Delta H$. To calculate the value of $\Delta H$ we need to know the position of the front axle as well as how low down the weight can practically be placed (the lower the better), we also need $m$ the mass added. Even then, although we can calculate the potential energy, this doesn't translate into a specific speed increase (even if it is all converted to kinetic energy). This is because the kinetic energy scales quadratically in velocity, so we need to know the velocity without the extra weight.

Comment: @Joe Yeah.  We'd have to make some guesses.  None of those things are impossible to gues, though.

Comment: @Mark: Sure, but since the question presumably relates to a real car, it it would be more reliable to simply measure them for the car in question.

Answer (score 2):

Having been in the derby and lost as a kid, and as parent, it is true that the angle tapers back, so you could gain a small amount of potential energy by placing it back as far as possible. I think the biggest issue is keeping the wheel(s) from vibrating in the track and generating extra friction. The wheel is solid plastic with a hole drilled through it, and a nail goes through the axial hole, into a slit on the bottom of the wood block. I've seen people polish and/or oil the part of the nail that contacts the wheel, with little apparent results. I suspect it probably has more to do with how well aligned the axles are
to the direction of motion and how well balanced the wheels are.That may be largely luck of the draw. Perhaps one should time all possible combinations of wheels and nails (4 factorial squared), and select the fastest one. You might also try both combinations of wheel orientations, but that gives you 96*96 possible combinations, which is too many to try them all.

Comment: Some competitions are more strict than others; I know during my undergrad, the engineering school's competition banned oiling the wheels.  (so I used powdered graphite, instead ... but I still lost out to the person who used nothing from the kit, and machined their car and used bearings for the wheels.

Comment: The wheels aren't solid any more, they're molded hollow plastic. The rest of your observations are right on.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from position of weight, I would add that what you really want to reduce is the the rolling resistance of the car.  One of the first areas I would target is the contact surface area of the wheels with the track. I would also reduce the amount of weight at the edges of the wheel.  For instance, instead of using wide, fat wheels, I would use wheels that taper down into a v-shape.
This will minimize the energy being used to spin up the wheels, as well as reduce the energy being transferred through friction to the surface.  I would also do whatever it takes to reduce friction in whatever bearing mechanism there is between the wheels/shaft/body of the racer.  In addition, I would work to reduce as much weight in the wheels as possible.  Again, the energy absorbed by the wheels needs to be minimized as much as possible.

So think along those lines...minimize rolling resistance, mimimize wheel weight, minimize wheel weight at the edge of the wheel. Maximize velocity at the bottom of the ramp.

addendum
I will add one little caveat, after looking at the track, there is an optimization problem here between energy lost due to friction, and the need to store energy to keep the vehicle moving.  A spin up of the wheels will store energy, which may be needed if your friction is high enough that you need that energy in the flatter portion of the track.  In any case, think in terms of transfer of energy from potenial to kinetic, what is stored on in the wheels, and what is lost due to friction, air resistance and rolling resistance.

Comment: Thanks for all these thoughts. Unfortunately you must use the supplied wheels with little modification. I'm not trying to go to heroic lengths anyway, but I *will* be adding weight to the car.

Answer (score 0):

Place the weight up front. Pull a hole shot and hope they don't catch you at the bottom. Worked for me!  I also dimpled the car,  all over, like a golf ball.